# Scrollbar disappearing when use modal on Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

So, I have tried put a modal on a link `<li>` in my menu, but when I click it, the scrollbar of the page disappears.

Look, this is my menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default bg-primary">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ><a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">History</a></li>
              <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title fontblue" id="myModalLabel"> Project</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<p class="line">
This page is... x x x
</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

I call 'js' in many forms

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Without click]

[image: after click modal]

look at the difference in scrollbar.

Comment: What have you got against scrollbars ;)

Comment: Works in this fiddle, http://fiddle.jshell.net/3aurrLyr/2/, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: nothing Jackson. I want show that but I do know how

Comment: Sirence when a work that in my site, the scrollbar hide after a click in link to show modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
divName.modal-open {
   overflow: scroll;
  }
```

this will work in v3 of bootstrap

Comment: Tks Nolawi. But I just need put this class on bootstrap css or substitute some other? And in wich div a apply this?

Comment: on the div you want the scroll on